# Why R linear ksvm don't use all support vectors

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm

I was playing with svm and I made this data:

```
x  y | type
-----------
1  1 |  1
2  2 |  1
2  0 |  1
0  0 | -1
0  1 | -1
1  0 | -1
```

and using this setting

```
svp <- ksvm(x,y,type="C-svc",kernel='vanilladot',C=100,scaled=c())
```

The result is like that (the support vectors are filled with red/black)

[image]

My question is why the other point `(0,1)` was not included as a support vector?